# Match substring with a preceeding OR combination

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to extract a substring in this format:

```
preceeding-string-data-i-want
```

Where:

```
preceeding-string
```

should be one of `stringA` or `stringB` or `stringC`.

I tried using:

```
(?:stringA|stringB|stringC)-?([A-Za-z\d]*)
```

but this leads to incorrect matches. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

-- EDIT --

Matching `stringA-pine-9000` gives me `stringA-pine` and `pine` as matches.

Comment: Incorrect matches of what sort? (Please elaborate on what erroneous behavior you're seeing.)

Comment: With your example, what do you *expect* to get as matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're wanting to match `pine-9000`, you probably need to include `-` in the set of characters allowed in your second group:

```
(?:stringA|stringB|stringC)-?([A-Za-z\d-]*)
```

Comment: Times like this, the only reaction is, do'h! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

`((stringA)|(stringB)|(stringC))-?([A-Za-z\d]*)`

It will match: `stringA-dataIWantfff`, `stringBDataIWant`, `stringC-DataIWant123` but not `stringD-DataIWant` and it will match up everything except the `@` in `stringC-DataIWant@`.

The problem I am seeing is that in the `data-i-want` section, you have included dashes (`-`), which you did not include in your original regex. I am assuming that the `data-i-want- does not contain dashes. If it does, then you can add it like so:

`((stringA)|(stringB)|(stringC))-?([A-Za-z\d\-]*)`

This will match something of the sort: `stringA-Data-I-Want`.